# How to post a json object from to an mvc action

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a mvc action

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult EditUser(ApplicationUser model)
```

ApplicationUser class is:

```
public class ApplicationUser
    {
        public int UserId { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string UserName { get; set; }

        public byte[] HashedPassword { get; set; }

        public bool IsActive { get; set; }
        public bool IsVerified { get; set; }
}
```

In jquery side I am doing:

```
   $.ajax({
        method: 'POST',
        url: '@Url.Content("~/UserAdmin/EditUser")',
        dataType: "json",
        data:  ....How do I post the object...???
    });
```

My question is how do I post the Json object to the method as I hit the break point but the object is null.

Comment: Where is this json object?

Answer (score 0):

Use [JSON.stringify](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) to reliably convert your JS object to JSON data for sending across the wire

```
var user = { 
    UserId: '31750',
    UserName: 'chugh97',
    HashedPassword: '...', 
    IsActive: true,
    IsVerified: true
};
...
dataType: 'json',
data: JSON.stringify(user),
...
```

Note - I would recommend making your `HashedPassword` a `string` type instead of a `byte[]`, it would be easier to deal with that client-side.

Comment: what is prop in this case?

Comment: Prop is the property of the object you're sending back, example:({ 'UserId' : 'value', 'UserName' : 'value', 'HashedPassword' : 'value', 'IsActive' : 'value', 'IsVerified': 'value' })  - value is the actual value which you are sending to and from the server.

Comment: @James I tried that but at the controller I get null. Essentially I have hard coded the values for test

Comment: @chugh97 that was just an example JS object, you would need to send an object up which matches your `ApplicationUser` properties (like the example Chris has shown).

Comment: try adding `contentType: "application/json"` to $.ajax

Comment: @chugh97 you need to set `contentType` to `application/json` otherwise the request will default to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` and won't make sense of the data.

Comment: I think you have to put that user object into another object like var data={model:user}. Here you can note i have used the parameter name model here. I had the same problem it worked for me.

Comment: @Sravan not in this case, you would only need to do that if your model on the server had a property called model which was of type User.